# Smooth scrolling is not working as expected, active link doesn't change it's color

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api

How can I make my WordPress theme Compatible with any smooth scrolling plugin?

I am using page scroll id plugin. It seems my theme is not compatible with that feature. 
In the one page theme some links change their colors some of them not.

What do I need to implement to make that compatible?

Trouble is not connected with specific plugin I tried almost all plugins, that provide that scrolling feature, and all of theme have the same trouble in my theme.

Comment: Let people know which theme you are currently using

Comment: It's new them and hasn't published on the internet yet.

Comment: how did you connect smooth scrolling with button colors? first check css of that buttons and provide more info about your problem